# Чи має запозичений термін “симуляція” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: from-english, синоніми, запозичені-слова, іншомовні-слова

Досить часто у сучасному повсякденному житті нам доводиться виконувати дії, які характеризуються терміном *симуляція*. *Симулюємо* багато чого: роботу, навчання, відпочинок, хворобу і т.д. і т.п. А чи існує в українській мові відповідник (та/або синонім) до зазначеного терміну?

Вікіпедія [надає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) наступне пояснення:

> **Симуляція** — імітація певної реальної речі, ситуації чи процесу. Процес симуляції зазвичай включає відтворення деяких ключових властивостей чи поведінки обраної фізичної або абстрактної системи.
>   Симуляцію проводять з різною метою — тренування та навчання персоналу, тестування технології в граничних умовах, тестування безпеки, розваги (відеоігри, симуляція невагомості). Також використовується науковцями для здійснення експериментів, які неможливі в реальності. Також симуляцію використовують, щоб продемонструвати можливі ефекти певних дій. Зазвичай симуляцію проводять, коли експерименти над реальною системою неможливі через її недосяжність, небезпеку або високу вартість таких експериментів.

СУМ-11 наводить [наступне](http://sum.in.ua/s/symuljacija):

> **СИМУЛЯ́ЦІЯ**, ї, жін. Удаване вираження певного фізичного стану, почуттів і т. ін. з метою введення кого-небудь в оману; удавання. *Все вміють [полонені], коли захочуть: восени, коли вкривали вдовам хати, отам уже працювали бев симуляції, робили на совість! (Олесь Гончар, Циклон, 1970, 81)*; *[Старший лікар:] Писав я не раз в протоколах і ввітах, що слідів симуляції в Камо нема (Олександр Левада, Драми.., 1967, 14)*.

На Словотворі до слова "симуляція" [пропонують](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/symuliatsiia) наступні варіанти:

> удавання, вдавання, відтворення.

Що, на мою думку, не зовсім відповідні.

Отже, чи має термін “*симуляція*” та похідні від терміну слова, додаткові (крім наведених) відповідні синоніми але українського походження?

Comment: Чому ви вважаєте *вдавання* не зовсім відповідним? У нас є прилад який *вдає* реальний літак і на запити повертає інформацію про свій стан. Він симулює літак.

Answer (score 2):

Згідно до СУМу "[удавати](http://sum.in.ua/s/udavaty)" (відповідно іменник буде "удавання") - "Робити вигляд, прикидатися; Надавати кому-небудь певного вигляду, образу, робити подібним до когось", і слово "симуляція" має у своєму визначені схоже значення, та навіть більше, як бачите там зазначається, що це те саме, що й "удавання". Згідно до [словника синонімів](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F), можна це слово замінити такими іменниками як "наподоблення", "підробка", "імітація" (хоч, слід врахувати, що це слово також іншомовного походження) "моделювання", "відтворення". Гадаю, що потрібно врахувати, що вживання того чи іншого слова-синоніма буде залежати від контексту, бо якщо у нас буде речення "Він симулював хворобу", то на варто казати "Він відтворив чи змоделював хворобу", а краще сказати "Він вдав, що був хворий" або ж "Він [прикинувся](http://sum.in.ua/s/prykydatysja), що був хворий", а от у реченні "Симуляція поведінки будівлі під час землетрусу", це слово уже краще замінити іменнико "моделювання".

Answer (score 1):

[Словник чужомовних слів Павла Штепи](//storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1307)

> **імітатор** — наподоблювач
>   **імітація** — наподоба
>   **імітувати** — наподоблювати, наподобити, понаподоблювати, сподоблювати, сподобити, посподоблювати, уподоблювати, уподобити, повподоблювати, наподібнювати, наподібнити, понаподібнювати, сподібнювати, сподібнити, посподібнювати, уподібнювати, уподібнити, повподібнювати
>
> **симулювати** — удавати, удати, повдавати, прикидатися, прикинутися, поприкидатися, дурити, здурювати, здурити, поздурювати, обдурювати, обдурити, пообдурювати, подурювати, подурити
>   **симулянт** — удавач, прикидько
>   **симуляція** — [сповидн](//goroh.in.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)ість, удавка

Відси *вдавання* для *сімуляція* підходить.

Comment: Анатолій, НМД, дуже правильно [пише](/a/4244). Павло Штепа розглядає лише одне з можливих значень слова _симулювати_ — «вдавати». А є ще й інше — «моделювати».